# JAVA Mail - Issue with outlook (Configured with GSuite)

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

Same mail with different images is send to (MAIL.TO) different user whereas CC and BCC remains the same
Gmail and other platforms are showing the correct images (Mail body) whereas when viewed on outlook the image of he user gets changed (In case of multiple mails - CC and BCC)

```
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(/* "related" */);

    messageBodyPart.setContent(mailTemplateValue.getTemplate(), "text/html");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // first image
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource employeeImage = new ByteArrayDataSource(dbResult.getImageData(), dbResult.getImageType());
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(employeeImage));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<employeeimage>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // second image
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource birthdayImage = new ByteArrayDataSource(convertImageToByteArray(birthdayImagePath),
            birthdayTemplateImageType);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(image2));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image2>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // third image
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource wishTextmage = new ByteArrayDataSource(convertImageToByteArray(birthdayWishTextImagePath),
            birthdayTemplateImageType);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(thirdimage));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<thirdimage>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // fourth image
    messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource footerImage = new ByteArrayDataSource(convertImageToByteArray(birthdayFooterImagePath),
            birthdayTemplateImageType);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(footerImage));
    messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<footerimage>");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // put everything together
    message.setContent(multipart);
}

Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: What would your question be?

Comment: @J_D Suppose there are three users (A, B,and C) , every user has a entry in database having email , unique code and image (blob) . Mail is triggered to all three users at the same time with image data coming from DB and mail ID comes from DB too. All three mail have same list of CC and BCC . When this mail is viewed by any CC or BCC on outlook (Office 365) images get swapped where User A has the image of user B and User B  has the image of User A. Same mail is correctly viewed on GMAIL and other platforms . mail id is ayush.deep@organisation.com (GSuite Configured).

Comment: So you're reporting a bug in Outlook?  I really don' t understand what you're doing.  Are you including the image data for all three users in the message you send?  Did you create a multipart/related message?  Does the html text of the message mention all three users and link to the image associated with each user?  Maybe an example of the entire message that's being displayed incorrectly in Outlook would help us understand what you're doing.

Comment: Every mail has three images , all in byte array data source  and a Subject as Text , two images out of these three images are same for every user . Only one image(User Image) is different and is user specific. The list of Mail recipients MAIL.CC and MAIL.BCC is same and get all the mails . MAIL.TO is user specific.The Problem is when any CC and BCC view the mail on microsoft outlook , the user image gets switched between mails . There is no such problem when the same mail is viewed by BCC and CC on Gmail , Android , iOS or any other platforms .